# Proper way to get next year from now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can get the next year in Rails?
I need to get only the year, without the date.
When I do `1.year.from_now` it returns a full date, not just the year.

Comment: _"using this code [...]"_ – you should tag your question accordingly if you are using Rails or Active Support.

Comment: You're clearly using Rails or ActiveSupport.  In which case you can do `1.year.from_now.year`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options to do this. But using your format, we can do it like this:

```
1.year.from_now.year
```

Comment: This obviously does not work in [tag:ruby]. Downvoted.

Comment: @mudasobwa Since the OP was asking a ROR question, I answered it that way. Missed it wasn't tagged ROR. But yes, you're right, it doesn't work in Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

Try these

```
Time.now.year + 1
```

output will be

```
2019
```

As suggest by @sschmeck you can try these also to get only next year

```
Time.now.year.succ
```

Comment: More fluent `Time.now.year.succ`

Comment: How about `Time.now.year.next`.

Comment: The only correct answer here so far, since the OP was not tagged with [tag:ruby-on-rails].

Answer (score 1):

[`today`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today)'s date:

```
require 'date'

Date.today
#=> #<Date: 2018-01-02 ...>
```

This day [`next_year`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_year):

```
Date.today.next_year
#=> #<Date: 2019-01-02 ...>
```

And finally its [`year`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-year):

```
Date.today.next_year.year
#=> 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
d = Time.now.year.next
```

Comment: This obviously does not work in [tag:ruby]. Downvoted.

Comment: Ruby `Time` instances don't respond to `next`.

Comment: Now this answer does not add any value to the one provided by @ig86 12 minutes before.